# merge request and sync forked repo

Tags: git, github

I forked from repoA, then others merged their PR into repoA, how do I sync repoA and my forkedOfRepoA?
Is it automatically sync?

I visit forkedOfRepoA I saw a message:

```
This branch is 37 commits behind repoA:master`
```

What I should do next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are working in a branch which is *not* `master` (as a best practice), you would simply [rebase](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing) your branch on top of repoA

```
cd /path/to/my/local/fork/clone
git remote repoA https://github.com/<original>/<repoA>
git fetch repoA
git switch my_working_branch
git rebase repoA/master
git push -f
```

> my issue is I want to sync my forkedRepoA:master with repoA:master

For that, this is easier:

```
cd /path/to/my/local/fork/clone
git remote repoA https://github.com/<original>/<repoA>
git fetch repoA

git switch master
git pull repoA master
git push

git switch my_working_branch
# resume working
```

Comment: isn't it easier just sync my forkedRepoA with repoA? imagine have to rebase everytime I push a new branch. I usually don't have conflict pushing, my issue is I want to sync my forkedRepoA:master with repoA:master

Comment: @NadielyJade Sure, I have edited my answer to address your comment

Comment: is it better if I setup remote url of repoA instead of needing to repeat those step? Then I'll just do `git pull upstream master`

Comment: @NadielyJade The git remote command is to be done only once. What needs to be repeated is the switch to master, pull and push.

Comment: hmm I see, why not `git remote add upstream https://github.com/<original>/<repoA>`?

Comment: @NadielyJade Sure, you can name it upstream. I only use repoA because that is the name you mentioned in your question.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are we using `git switch` here?

Comment: @Pytth Because git checkout is obsolete and confusing: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57066202/6309

Comment: @VonC Super interesting! Thanks for that tidbit.